# java - Student Class Compile Errror

Tags: java

i have written this java code and i get an error can anyone tell me why? the code is to create a student class and will be tested.
i am new to java so any help will be appreciated 
this is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
private static void main(String[] args) 
    {

                private String forName;
                private String surName;
                private String studentID;
                private String degreeScheme;

            //This is the Constructor of the 
class Student
                public Student(String name) {
                    this.forName = forName;
                }
            //Assign the surname of the student 
                public void stuSurname (String 
stuSurname){
                    surName = stuSurname;
                }
            //Assign the student ID to the 
student
                public void stuID (String stuID){
                    studentID = stuID;
                }
            //Assign the Degree of the Student
                public void stuDegree (String 
stuDegree){
                    degreeScheme = stuDegree;

                }

            //Print the student details
                public void printStudent(){

System.out.println("Forname:"+ forName);

System.out.println("Surename:"+ surName);
                    System.out.println("Student 
ID:"+ studentID);
                    System.out.println("Degree 
Scheme:"+ degreeScheme);
                }
            // setter
            public void setForName(String 
forName) {
                this.forName = forName;
            }

            // getter
            public String getForName() {
                return forName;
            }

     }
 }
```

and this is the error that i get:

```
TheRealFawcett:lab8 therealfawcett$ javac 
Student.java
Student.java:8: error: illegal start of 
expression
                private String forName;
                ^
Student.java:49: error: class, interface, or enum 
expected
}
^
2 errors
TheRealFawcett:lab8 therealfawcett$
```

i don't understand why i get this error as i thought my main method was correct.

Comment: Class members and methods belong in the class itself, not in the main method

Comment: In other words you can't declare a local variable (which what you get when you put variables inside a method) as `private`.  Private stuff goes outside the method.

Comment: @thatotherguy What does that mean? how would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) belong to the [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html) and not to to the method. Also [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) have to be at class level.

In your code all fields and methods are in the main method, which is not correct.

The following snippet shows a correct version:

```
public class Student {
    private static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("Charles");
    }

    private String forName;
    private String surName;
    private String studentID;
    private String degreeScheme;

    //This is the Constructor of the 
    public Student(String name) {
        this.forName = forName;
    }

    //Assign the surname of the student 
    public void stuSurname(String stuSurname) {
        surName = stuSurname;
    }

    //Assign the student ID to the student
    public void stuID(String stuID) {
        studentID = stuID;
    }

    //Assign the Degree of the Student
    public void stuDegree(String stuDegree) {
        degreeScheme = stuDegree;
    }

    //Print the student details
    public void printStudent() {
        System.out.println("Forname:" + forName);
        System.out.println("Surename:" + surName);
        System.out.println("Student ID:" + studentID);
        System.out.println("Degree Scheme:" + degreeScheme);
    }

    // setter
    public void setForName(String forName) {
        this.forName = forName;
    }

    // getter
    public String getForName() {
        return forName;
    }
}
```

To learn more about the Java Classes and Objects you can follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) official tutorial.

Comment: I have now changed my code is there a way i can speak with you more about some other issues that i have

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.